# Add and remove class on a p element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class called `active` to the `p` children of a `div` using a click event. The first click adds the class to the `p`, but if I click on the second div the previous inserted class must be removed.

Here is a very basic example:

```js
$('.changeP').on('click',function(){
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).children('p').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active { color: orange; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
  <div class="changeP">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <p>Lorem ipsum loret</p>
  </div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
  <div class="changeP">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <p>Lorem ipsum loret</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ned to remove the class from all elements that have it, not just the clicked element. To do that change `$(this)` to `$('.active')`. Also note that your outer `div` elements are missing a closing tag. Try this:

```js
$('.changeP').on('click', function() {
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).children('p').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active { color: orange; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
  <div class="changeP">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <p>Lorem ipsum loret</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
  <div class="changeP">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <p>Lorem ipsum loret</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution:

```
 $('.changeP').on('click',function(){
   $('p').removeClass('active');
   $(this).find('p').addClass('active');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove class `active` from all `.changeP p` elements (paragraphs inside `changeP`), then add the class to the clicked one:

```js
$('.changeP').on('click', function() {
  $('.changeP p').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all '.changeP p'
  $(this).children('p').addClass('active'); // add it to this p
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
  <div class="changeP">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <p>Lorem ipsum loret</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="changeP">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      <p>Lorem ipsum loret</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for jQuery `toggleClass` function which adds the class if not added previously and removes if already added.

```
$('.changeP').on('click', function() {
  $(this).children('p').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('.changeP').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $p = $this.find('p'),
        $activeP = $('.changeP .active');
    if(!$p.hasClass('active')) {
        $activeP.removeClass('active');
        $p.addClass('active');
    }
});
```